# Extra JSON value to display in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

In my app, I get the following response for a failed user login:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "User account is disabled."
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to get this in Objective-C to only display: `User account is disabled.`?

When I do the following, it displays:

```
(
    "User account is disabled."
)
```

Code:

`NSLog(@"%@",[JSONValue objectForKey:@"non_field_errors"]);`

How can I remove the parentheses and double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses is there because you are getting response in such a way. you can access your data using following way.

```
JSONValue[@"non_field_errors"][0] // This will return User account is disabled.
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the value for key *non_field_errors* is a JSON Array (Notice the square brackets). So use this :

```
NSArray *arr = [JSONValue objectForKey:@"non_field_errors"];
NSLog(@"%@",[arr firstObject]);
```

or just cram it all in one line

```
[(NSArray*)[JSONValue objectForKey:@"non_field_errors"] firstObject];
```